# Regex Cucumber Gherkin for numbers float

Tags: java, maven, selenium, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I have feature file as #

```
And Pick random value between '100.3' and '200.9'
```

When I execute Feature am getting as

To use random function  I need value to double , not sure how value (float/double) is divided as int

```
@And("^Pick random value between '(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)' and '(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)'$")
public void pickrandomvaluebetween(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) throws Throwable {
```

Can some one help ? not sure if am missing any dependencies

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want here is to capture the low and high point of the range as separate numbers.  Try using this pattern:

```
@And("^Pick random value between '(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)' and '(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)'$")
public void pickrandomvaluebetween(String min, String max) throws Throwable {
    // ... parse min/max as floats or doubles
    // do something
}
```

### Demo

The pattern `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` says to match one or more digits, following by an optional decimal place and one or more digits.  The `?:` you see inside inner parentheses should tell Java *not* to capture the decimal point portion as a separate pattern.  Rather, as the demo above shows, only the entire (possibly floating point) number is captured.

Answer (score 1):

```
@And("^Pick random value between '([\d\.]+)' and '([\d\.]+)'$") 
public void pickrandomvaluebetween(String minValueStr, String maxValueStr) {
   float minValue = Float.parseFloat(minValueStr);
   float maxValue = Float.parseFloat(maxValueStr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Cucumber-jvm v3.x, you can use Cucumber expressions, so you will not have to use Regex anymore. Source: https://cucumber.io/blog/2018/05/19/announcing-cucumber-jvm-3-0-0